# Google is indexing pages with old URLs

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, search-engine-indexing

I run a doctor directory website. It has profile pages on individual doctors. This was the url structure:

```
www.example.com/docprofile/23/
```

We recently changed the url structure to: `www.example.com/james-smith/`

We've done 301 redirection so it redirects properly from the old url to the new. We've also added the canonical tag to the new url. Some of the urls have already started getting indexed by google.

But today i checked the Google Search console and under HTML improvements I saw Duplicated title tags issues. It's showing both the old and new url and saying it has duplicate title tags. How do fix this and would I get a Panda penalty or something?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, no chance of any kind of penalty. First please check 301 redirection and canonical tag have implemented correctly and then to index the pages quickly, you can do the following things:

1. Upload xml sitemap on new website
2. Submit sitemap in GWT tool Fetch
3. Fetch new pages in GWT

Answer (score 2):

No you will not get any penalty. Some time Search console takes some time to update their data.

There was a same problem had been occurred with me. But after some days, the issues had been resolved automatically.

So don't worry if you have done 301 redirection properly.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you will not get any penalty for this.

*If you have done the redirection correctly*, It will be fine,But it takes some time for the google to update its database in all locations.

May be, Google still has not completed crawling all your URL, You wait for sometime, It will happen.

If you want to do it urgently, Then login to 1) Google Web Master 2) Crawl 3) Fetch as Google 4) Enter the URL and then do "Fetch"

I hope this helps. But it is not guaranteed.